# What can I use instead of "Set Identity Insert On"?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have stored procedure in SQL Server. In this procedure, I delete duplicate records and insert one unique records to table. When I insert new unique record I am using below script.

```
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT tbl_personnel_info ON
    
    INSERT INTO tbl_personnel_info (pk_id, first_name, last_name, department, age, phone_number)

    SELECT pk_id, first_name, last_name, department, age, phone_number
    FROM #Unique

    SET IDENTITY_INSERT tbl_personnel_info Off
```

Everthing is okey with this script but in the production `SET IDENTITY_INSERT` command needs to ALTER permission. Giving this permission should be dangerous so I can't give this permission. Also I must insert old pk_id instead of new. How can I do this without `SET IDENTITY_INSERT` command.

For example I have those records.

| first_name | last_name | department | age | phone_number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | Doe | IT | 21 | XXX |
| John | Doe | Finance | 22 | YYY |
| John | Doe | HR | 23 | ZZZ |

And the record i want is

| first_name | last_name | department | age | phone_number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | Doe | IT | 23 | YYY |

I also have my wanted record in the #Unique table. I want to delete 3 records and add record which is in the unique table.

Comment: I suspect you have an XY problem.

Comment: @PSK Are you talking about keeping one record and updating that record instead of insert new one?

Comment: @PSK because suppose I have 5 record. The unique record I added is a combination of these records. For example I get one column value from 2.record , I get another column value from 3.record like that. So I cant directly delete all records and keep one.

Comment: Why would this need to be a regular thing that is run by a stored procedure and needs to be run by many users and not just someone with alter permission? Would it not make more sense to simply fix whatever it is that is causing the duplicates in the first place (e.g. by calling stored procedure rather than direct insert/update, or even an Instead of Trigger to validate inserts/updates)  - then all you need to do is a one off clean up of the data where ongoing permissions aren't an issue.

Comment: @PSK Your answer seems unhelpful as it didn't solve problem that was presented. It didn't solve problem of having to use SET IDENTITY_INSERT to insert new unique rows in the table that were assembled from deleted records..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I still believe that you have a bit of an xy problem here, and you would be better off preventing the duplicates at source rather than having a clean up procedure that needs to be regularly run by people other than the sa, but to actually answer your question one option would be not not delete the records you want to retain.

If you generate your `#Unique` table before you do the delete, then you can simply use something like:

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

UPDATE  p WITH (UPDLOCK, SERIALIZABLE)
SET     first_name = u.first_name,
        last_name = u.last_name,
        department = u.department,
        age = u.age,
        phone_number = u.phone_number
FROM    tbl_personnel_info  AS p
        INNER JOIN #Unique AS u
            ON u.pk_id = p.pk_id
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (   SELECT u.first_name, u.last_name, u.department, u.age. u.phone_number
            INTERSECT
            SELECT p.first_name, p.last_name, p.department, p.age. p.phone_number
        );

DELETE p
FROM   tbl_personnel_info AS p
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #Unique AS u WHERE u.pk_id = p.pk_id);


COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

This will update the records you want to retain and were originally planning to re-insert(but only if there is a value that needs to be updated), then only delete any records that don't exist in your temp table.

One big issue you may face here is foreign keys, you would presumably also need to tidy up any records related to the records you are deleting? This is another reason why you would be much better off preventing the duplicates at source and doing one single clear up (therefore stored procedure not required).

For a bit of an analogy, you have a hole in your boat and your current approach is to grab a bucket and keep scooping water over board, which you'll be doing forever and the hole will only get bigger. The hole is as small as it will ever be right now - so now is the best time to plug it.